# Email Cc not working

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm trying to send email via PHP script. I can send successfully but no email arriving to the recipient under Cc field.. Is there something wrong with the headers?

```html
function send_email($to,$subject,$body,$cc = ''){
  require_once "Mail.php";

  $from = "<removed>";

  $host = "smtp.domain.com";
  $username = "<removed>";
  $password = "<removed>";

  $headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject,
  'Cc' => $cc);
  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

  if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = $mail->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($response);

  }else {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Email sent to " . $to;
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
}
```

Comment: the silence is because no one uses pear mailer theses days.

Comment: I'm using this now - https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHPMailer (from your comment), add the addresses like so:

```
$mail->addCC('somebodyelse@bla.com', 'somebody else');
$mail->addCC('otherguy@blabla.com', 'other somebody');
```

Or call the `addCC` method in a loop for your convenience.

Comment: Great! All hail PHPMailer! ;) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I moved to PHPMailer and It is now working..

This is the working code

```html
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

$to = $_POST['rcpt'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$body = $_POST['msgBody'];
$cc = $_POST['cc'];

send_email($to,$subject,$body,$cc);

function send_email($to,$subject,$body,$cc = ''){
  require_once "Mail.php";

  $from = "monitor<monitor@m2techtronix.com>";

  $host = "smtp.domain.com";
  $username = "monitor@m2techtronix.com";
  $password = "gUZfE6SVLV";

//  $headers = array ('From' => $from,
//  'To' => $to,
//  'Subject' => $subject,
//  'Cc' => $cc);
  $headers['From']    = $from;
  $headers['To']      = $to.", ".$cc;
  $headers['Subject'] = $subject;


  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

  if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = $mail->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($response);

  }else {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Email sent to " . $to;
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
}
?>
```

Required classes can be found here - https://github.com/romelemperado/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I send a mail using PEAR's Mail package.
Note you also need to install the Mail/Mime package - which is trivial to do.

```
<?php
require_once 'Mail.php';
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';

$from = "from@example.com";
$msg = "this is a test";
$to = 'to@example.com';
$cc = 'cc@example.com';
$sbj = "Testing";


$message = new Mail_mime();
$message->setTXTBody($msg);
$message->setHTMLBody("<html><body>$msg</body></html>");
$body = $message->get();

$extraheaders = [  
            "From"      => $from,
            "Cc"        => $cc,
            "To"        => $to,
            "Subject"   => $sbj 
];

$mail = Mail::factory("mail");

$headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
// In case you have more than one address in the $to variable.
$addresses = implode(",", [$to]);

if ($mail->send($addresses, $headers, $body)) {
    echo "Successfully Sent";
} else {
    echo "Message Failed";
}
```